# IE hangs with nested ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have webpage that has paging for an outer loop of elements, that when clicked will expand, make a call to the server, then display another table filled with paginated rows. I only experience this hang in IE which I have come to find seems like a common problem.

The outer results set will only display 25 rows at a time. The inner will also only display 25 rows at a time. Only one accordian panel can be opened at a time. I am using track by and one time bindings. The repeat-starts both have corresponding repeat-ends. The outer result set loads very quickly with no hangs.

I am using angularjs 1.5.8.

Some sample snippets of html:

```
<div class="accordionHdr" ng-repeat-start="(index, obj1) in ::vm.obj1Array track by $index">

   //normal accordian panel stuff here. clicking a panel calls server to get inner results

   //normal table code
   <tr ng-repeat-start="(index2, obj2) in ::vm.obj2Array track by $index">
      <td>several cells in here</td>
   </tr>

</div>
```

What can I do to eliminate this hang that only exist in IE? Thanks in advance

Comment: maybe too much xhr requests at once?

Comment: i only make one initially, then one once an accordian panel has been clicked. So, only one is fired at a time